# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los headers que se envían a un sitio desde Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

Estoy analizando un sitio y quiero obtener el token que se envía en una de las peticiones que se realizan. Estuve buscando información en varios sitios pero no logré encontrar la manera de obtener los headers que se **"envían"** de cada petición; no los que recibo.

Ejemplo de mi código:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
headers = driver.requests  # Quiero obtener una lista de los headers que se envían en c/petición
print("Requests", driver.requests)  # Pero obtengo los headers que el servidor responde
```

No hay problema si hace falta el uso de otra librería.

Gracias!

Comment: Selenium usa un webdriver (geckodriver si usas firefox). Es webdriver quién controla las cabeceras de igual modo que lo hace el navegador. Si por "envío" te refieres a un código javascript que se conecta con un servidor para obterner un token, olvídate de interceptar nada por este camino. Eso sí, si quieres saber qué cabeceras envías, usa algún _http-echo_, por ejemplo <http://scooterlabs.com/echo.json>.

Comment: La función de selenium es testear el interface web usando un navegador remoto (_webdriver_). Si quieres control del navegador de lo que envía y recibe, usa otra cosa, como por ejemplo [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/) que funciona con python. No te pongo ejemplo porque aún no he probado suficientemente playwright.

Comment: Hola. Disculpa que responda recién. Es lo que buscaba!! Gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de ChemaCortes el problema se puede resolver usando Playwright: https://pypi.org/project/playwright/

Paso un ejemplo publicado en el link anterior:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()

    def log_and_continue_request(route, request):
        print(request.url, request.headers)
        route.continue_()

    # Log and continue all network requests
    page.route("**/*", log_and_continue_request)

    page.goto("http://todomvc.com")
    browser.close()
```

Adjunto documentación del apartado de Networks que sería útil: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/network